# multi-dimensional vectors and pointers to vectors

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am trying to store pointers to vectors of pointers to vectors in a vector. (I hope that wasn't too mind boggling). Basically, I have a vector and I want to store multiple matrices in it, hence the 3 dimensions. There seems to be a problem with the way I am accessing elements. I don't particuarlily understand the error because the 3rd dimension is a pointer to a vector of ints. I don't think that should change the way you access the ints.

```
using namespace std;

vector< vector< vector<int>* >* > matrixHolder;

int main() {

    vector< vector<int>* >* a;

    a->push_back(new vector<int>(10, 0));

    matrixHolder.push_back(a);

    matrixHolder[0][0][0] = 5; //Line 34


    return 0;
}
```

main.cpp:34: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘std::vector < int, std::allocator < int> >*’

Comment: I need to use pointers because the vectors need to be stored in the heap. I am gathering the vectors from the call stack, meaning, I am gather the vectors from functions on the call stack. So the data stored in these functions are lost when the function is finished. I need to capture that data in the heap.

Comment: try http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/456547/How-to-use-Multidimensional-vector-in-Cplusplus

Comment: @brettgag Why can't you just move the data?

Comment: Try to pass reference to maxtrixholder to function

Comment: `vector<T>` stores its data on the heap already. Why do the vectors themselves need to be on the heap?

Comment: @MarceloCantos "`vector<T>` stores its data on the heap already" -- says who?

Comment: @Jefffrey: I'm a pragmatist, not a lawyer.

Comment: @Jefffrey: Says the C++ standard, unless you've overloaded or replaced `operator new`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, could you please tell me what exact section of the standard mentions it?

Comment: @Jefffrey: C++11 12.5 describes the free store, and how the default `operator new` allocates memory from it. 20.6.9 describes how `std::allocator` uses `operator new`, and 23.3.6 defines vector, including the default use of `std::allocator`. I hope you're not just quibbling about the use of the word "heap", rather than the more Standardese "free store".

Comment: @MikeSeymour, yes, I am. :)

Answer (score 3):

`matrixHolder[0]` is of type `vector<vector<int>*>*`, a pointer to a vector of pointers to a vector of ints.

`matrixHolder[0][0]` dereferences `matrixHolder[0]`, so it is of type `vector<vector<int>*>`, a vector of pointers to a vector of ints.

`matrixHolder[0][0][0]` gets the first element of `matrixHolder[0][0]`, and is of type `vector<int>*`, a pointer to a vector of ints.

So when you do this:

```
matrixHolder[0][0][0] = 5;
```

The error is exactly as described by your compiler, an invalid conversion from `int` (that's what `5` is) to `vector<int>*` (that's what `matrixHolder[0][0][0]` is)

The correct syntax for this terrible abomination is:

```
(*(*matrixHolder[0])[0])[0] = 5;
```

Or you could also do this:

```
matrixHolder[0][0][0][0][0] = 5;
```

But that is probably confusing as to what is going on, making it look like you have a 5 dimensional array.

By the way, you're wrong.  You don't need to use pointers, but I won't try to convince you of that here.

**On another note:**

```
a->push_back(new vector<int>(10, 0));
```

`a` is an uninitialized pointer, and you just dereferenced it.  That's undefined behavior.

Comment: love the word "abomination" in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

(For a more well-engineered solution...)

Don't use `vector<vector<T>>` to store matrices. The usual solution is a single array (e.g., `vector<T>`), using simple arithmetic to compute offsets (`x + width * y` for row-major storage):

```
int main() {
    constexpr int w = 10, h = 10;
    vector<vector<int>> matrixHolder(1, vector<int>(w * h, 0));
    int x = 2, y = 3;
    matrixHolder[0][x + w * y] = 5;
}
```

Sorry for the C++11 syntax.